# Remove line from file without mutating the buffer variable in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, mutation

I am new to Nodejs

I have written a function that reads contents from a file and stores into a variable as an array. And finally I am mutating the variable and writing it to a file. See below:

```
function(file, item) {
   return fs.readLine(file).then(function(contents) {
       var data = contents.split(/\n/);
       data.splice(data.indexOf(item), 1);
       return fs.writeFile(file, data.join(/\n/));
});
}
```

Is there a way to do the same without mutating the variable or even having had to store the contents of a file into a variable and delete it in node js?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to mutate the variable with `data.splice()` then you can use `data.slice()` that doesn't mutate the original array. See the docs:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Also instead of reading the contents of the file into a variable, you can create a readable stream and filter out the line that you don't want.

See how I created my `filt` module that filters lines of standard input:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/filt

The source code and a lot of examples are on GitHub:

- https://github.com/rsp/node-filt

Basically what you can do here is - using the handy `split` module - something like this:

```
fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(split()).on('data', (line) => {
    // if line is something ... etc.
});
```